# Unable to publish non-monolithic script module to local PowerShell Gallery with 7 or more functions

Tags: powershell

**Problem:**
I am unable to successfully publish a non-monolithic script module to my local PowerShell Gallery when using PowerShell 5.1 and my module contains 7 or more functions. Publishes fine with 6 or less functions.

Example: FunctionsToExport = 'Get-Test1', 'Get-Test2 ', 'Get-Test3', 'Get-Test4', 'Get-Test5', 'Get-Test6', 'Get-Test7'

The publish always hangs at 'VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Publish-Module" on target…', but never completes.

I am not seeing any errors, so I am not sure why it is hanging.

**What does work:**
I can successfully publish my non-monolithic script module to my local PowerShell Gallery when it contains 6 or less functions.

Example: FunctionsToExport = 'Get-Test1', 'Get-Test2 ', 'Get-Test3', 'Get-Test4', 'Get-Test5', 'Get-Test6'

This works fine: VERBOSE: Successfully published module…

If I simply add one more function and update the manifest, I can no longer publish without it hanging again at the same place.

I am pretty sure I am missing a step, but I am having trouble figuring out what I missed.

I am learning the non-monolithic script module design from [Mike F Robbins](https://mikefrobbins.com/about/) by reading his [blog posts](https://pinboard.in/u:j0hns/t:non-monolithic/t:mikefrobbins) and watching his [presentations](https://pinboard.in/u:J0hnS/t:presentation/t:mikefrobbins). The gist of this design is each function is in a separate PS1 file that is dot sourced from the PSM1 file.

Summary of how I build my script modules:

- Create new script module scaffolding using custom Plaster template.
- Add functions to the folder named Public.
- Update module version and FunctionsToExport section in manifest.
- Use PsDeploy or Publish-Module to deploy to a local PowerShell Gallery.
- The local PowerShell Gallery is just a folder on my data drive G:\JnPowerShellGallery.

This is how I am publishing my module to my local PSGallery.

```bsh
Publish-Module -Path 'G:\_temp\JnTestModule' -Repository JnPowerShellGallery -NuGetApiKey 'AnyStringWillDo' -Verbose -InformationAction Continue
```

Here is a OneDrive link to my test module.
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlsrG1Yfr5pHgts0RCM--SmRnUf3AA

Output of $PSVersionTable

```
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.590                                                                                                                              
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                    
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                    
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.590                                                                                                                             
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                            
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                        
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                        
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

I am so close to building my first release pipeline for my PowerShell modules, but I am stuck at this point.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you post your output of `$PSVersionTable`

Comment: Ok, I added the output for $PSVersionTable to my post. Sorry about formatting, I couldn't get it formatted as a table.

Comment: Related?  [Publish-Module fails to publish when large number of functions are exported](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/issues/344)  That GitHub issue mentions the `Publish-Module` command throwing an error, though, unlike in this question where it hangs...

Comment: @trebleCode Thanks for formatting the $PSVersionTable output. I just found out how to do it right. No tabs, only 4 spaces max, format as code.

Comment: @BACON I am not sure if the tag limit is related to my issue at this point, but I will try to look into this further. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a solution for those stuck on corporate version 5.1 and cannot use 6 or 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I just found out I can publish my module successfully using PowerShell Core 6.2.0!

Joel on  http://slack.poshcode.org/ powershell-help channel suggested to change the .psd1 file encoding to UTF8 with BOM. He said PowerShell 5  doesn't like .psd1 files that don't have BOM. They are encoded with UTF8 by default in vscode. I did try changing the encoding, but this did not fix my problem.

Thanks to his suggestion, I thought of trying to publish my module with PowerShell Core 6.2.0 and it worked!

This does not exactly solve the problem with PowerShell 5.1, but I don't mind switching to PowerShell Core 6.2.0  to publish my modules. This solves my problem.

Comment: Thanks! Spent a whole day struggling with this, works from PowerShell 7  (Core) :)